# Is wp_reset_postdata always necessary?

Tags: wp-query

After run a query

```
$posts = (array)new WP_Query($args);
```

I use this data to do some calculation on post meta. I didn't display the posts. Do I still need to use `wp_reset_postdata` after the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you called the_post() on the query, then yes. This resets the global variables used in the main queries.